# How do i get the execution time of an View

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

I created a view for testing purposes and would like to see the execution time.

But i was unable to find an option to do this could somebody please guide me how i could get this information.

Comment: Have a look at SET STATISTICS (TIME/IO) ON and do your select from your View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

little easy way

```
set statistics time on

select * from [dbo].[ViewName]

set statistics time off
```

then see your message window

[image]

For more information of [Query Execution Plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Comment: oh gosh, i tried `set statistics time on/off` but haven't looked in my Messages Tab thanks for this hint :D

Comment: It is unlikely to be an issue, and certainly hasn't stopped me from voting for this answer, but it is worth noting, that setting statistics on, *can* (not necessarily will) affect performance of the query it is measuring if it contains a scalar udf. [This article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/91724/) touches on the subject in more detail about half way through. This of course could all be moot if the view does not contain a scalar udf, but could be useful for anyone reading in future.